# JQueryUI widget function scope problem

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, widget, this, slickgrid

I'm not sure exactly how to describe this problem, but I'm making a JQueryUI widget out of the very useful SlickGrid JQuery plugin. Slickgrid allows for setting a function used as a "filter" to enable searching rows on the client. Like this...

```
_filter: function (item) {
            if (this.options.searchString == null)
            { return true; }
            if (this.options.searchString.length == 0)
            { return true; }
            for (var prop in item) {
                if (item[prop] != null) {
                    if (item[prop].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase()) > -1)
                    { return true; }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }


self.options.dataView.setFilter(self._filter);
```

My problem is that once `_filter` gets called, `this` is set to the window element, and no longer holds a reference to the widget, so all of my options are unavailable. How can I tell `_filter` what term the user is searching for in the grid?

Difficulty: multiple widget instances will be on the page, each with their own separate filter. Also, I'd prefer not to modify the way SlickGrid works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best answer, but here's what I came up with:

Via the advice on http://www.robertsosinski.com/2009/04/28/binding-scope-in-javascript/ , in my create function, I wrote

```
this._filter = function (item) {

                if (this.options.searchString == null)
                { return true; }
                if (this.options.searchString.length == 0)
                { return true; }
                for (var prop in item) {
                    if (item[prop] != null) {
                        if (item[prop].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.options.searchString.toLowerCase()) > -1)
                        { return true; }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            } .bind(this);
```

Which bound the scope to the widget.